# sending a put request returns http error 400 using jersey

Tags: java, ember.js, jackson, jersey-2.0, put

I am trying to send a PUT request from the client to the server in Ember.js (using model.save() on ember which generates a put request)
whenever I put the model inside:

```
@PUT
@Secured
@Path("/{id}")
public void update(@Context SecurityContext sc, @PathParam("id") String id, Model model){
    System.out.println("here");
}
```

the model Pojo class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use=Id.NAME)
@JsonTypeName(value = "model")
public class Model extends AnotherModel{

}
```

whenever the model is inside the update method the client receives HTTP error 400 and the "here" message isn't getting  printed into the console.
when I put a comment on the model on the update method "here" message is being printed to the console.

the class AnotherModel contains alot of fields 
here is a json that is being generated in the client:

```
{"model":{"name":"snapshothour","is_renameable":true,"memory_size":1073741824,"memory_used":1468006,"has_memory_limitation":true,"min_memory_size":1,"max_memory_size":1000000,"max_cluster_memory_size":20,"type":"redis","status":"active","version":"3.0.5","eviction_policy":"volatile-lru","dataset_init":"greenfield","private_endpoint":"","public_endpoint":"redis-14556.nadavcluster:14556","backup_status":"","backup_failure_reason":"","backup_progress":-1,"import_status":"idle","import_failure_reason":"","import_progress":-1,"export_status":null,"export_failure_reason":null,"export_progress":null,"data_persistence":"snapshot-1h","has_persistence":true,"replication":true,"is_replica_source":false,"sync_enabled":false,"activated_on":"2016-04-17T09:33:25Z","last_changed_time":"2016-04-28T07:51:27Z","cloud_name":"AWS","plan_size":0,"plan_max_connections":10,"plan_cloud":"AWS/eu-west-1","plan_name":"Standard PAYG","backup_storage_type":"","backup_path":null,"backup_interval":null,"last_backup_time":null,"has_backup":false,"sharding":false,"is_sharding_supported":true,"authentications":[{"id":"40007269","ssl":true,"authentication_ssl_client_cert":"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\r\nyjyvXmgO8C4lCwGM0nOHmCGhUw==\r\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----","authentication_ssl_client_cert_fp":"2F:4F:76:47:08:AD:F7:0E:66:09:18:B7:0B:F5:35:0B:00:1D:C5:F9","authentication_redis_pass":"","authentication_sasl_uname":null,"authentication_sasl_pass":null,"authentication_pseudo_key":null,"bdb":"40007269","authenticationSecurityGroups":[{"account_id":"","security_group_name":"","authentication":"40007269"}],"authenticationSips":[{"id":"114310","ip":"154.51.60.0/24","authentication":"40007269"},{"id":"114308","ip":"154.50.60.1","authentication":"40007269"}]}],"subscription":"21500","bdbBackups":[],"bdbAlerts":[{"id":"40007269","bdb_high_latency":false,"bdb_high_latency_threshold":0,"bdb_high_throughput":true,"bdb_high_throughput_threshold":1000,"bdb_low_throughput":true,"bdb_low_throughput_threshold":10,"bdb_size":true,"bdb_size_threshold":80,"bdb_high_syncer_lag":false,"bdb_high_syncer_lag_threshold":0,"bdb_syncer_unable_to_sync":false,"bdb_connection_limit":true,"bdb_connection_limit_threshold":80,"bdb":"40007269"}],"shardKeyRegexs":[]}}
```

Thanks for the assist